# Grails/Hibernate: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have a domain as follow:

```
class Author {
    String id
    static hasMany = [accounts: Account]
    static belongsTo = Account
    static mapping = {
        accounts joinTable: [name: "SOMETABLE", key: 'SOMEFIELD'], 
                 ignoreNotFound: true
    }
    static constraints = {}
}
```

I get the following error when no record are found. I tried the ignoreNotFound, it not working.

```
error message: accounts=org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: 
No row with the given identifier exists: 
[com.myapplication.Account#123465489785]
```

it happens when trying to select join 2 records that you dont have access to insert in the db.
Is there a workaround, please?

Answer (score 3):

it means there is no row in your `Account` table with id `123465489785`. Your author has an account with id 123465489785. Hibernate cannot find it so it throws an exception. if its a new account make the id on the account null so that hibernate knows its a new row.

Comment: I understand that it means no row in the Author table exist. But is there a way to ask grails to ignore it? Can we tell grails to just return an empty list?

Comment: what are you trying to do? save an author?

Comment: This is a legacy database. I'm just reading the record. We will not update any records. There's a many-to-many relationship, that why I had to specified the joinTable.

Comment: Basically, the issue is in reading the Author record, it throws the "No row with the given identifier exists" exception which break the page.

Comment: Maybe is there a way to catch the exception on the gsp page?

Comment: then try and do this. `select * from author where accountId=123465489785` and `select * from account where accountId =  123465489785`. if the first one gives you 1 row and the second query 0 rows, it means your author has an attached account that doesnt exist

Comment: My record has an attached account that does not exist.

Comment: I'm trying to handle this use case on the gsp page

Comment: then you should create an account with id  123465489785, or change the authors accountid to an id that exists

Comment: I don't have this option to create account. I'm reading legacy data.

Comment: you should also state on your question 1) that it happens when trying to `select join` 2 that you dont have access to insert in the db. its harder to assume what your are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Adding `ignoreNotFound = true` mapping solves the issue according to the [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/ignoreNotFound.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Author.findById(id)` instead of `Author.get(id)`